# What do i create at thread with a function with parameters?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, parameter-passing

What do i create at thread with a function with parameters?

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(fetchQuotes(cp)));

void fetchQuotes(SomeObject obj)
{
    [DoSomething With SomeObject] 
}
```

Comment: Most people will want to use TPL (the new task library) rather than creating threads manually these days. So first, make sure you really want to do this and not use Task<T>

Comment: Does Task run on a separate thread? If yes then would not mind using task, else i will have to use  thread.

Comment: Anders, why a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: Serge: It wasn't an answer to the original question, if he chooses to go with TPL he will face the same question of parameters only with a different syntax. So I felt it should be a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach here is to use a closure over the *non-parameterised* (`ThreadStart`) signature:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => fetchQuotes(cp));
...
t.Start();
```

This is static-checked for correctness at compile-time, and convenient (you can pass any number of parameters, for example).

The other approach is to pass `object` as the parameter (`ParameterizedThreadStart`):

```
Thread t = new Thread(fetchQuotes);
...
t.Start(cp);
...
void fetchQuotes(object obj)
{
    SomeObject obj2 = (SomeObject) obj;
    [DoSomething With SomeObject] 
}
```

here we are passing `object`, so not type-checked at compile time. "braindead" errors will only surface at runtime.

Comment: Thanks. this works.. now i need to know how do i know when a function of the thread has finished working?

Comment: @Taufiq - the easiest thing to do there is to pass a callback into the method that you can invoke when complete; however, while I'm not sure that it is quite as "far along" as *everyone is using it*, the TPL (`Task` API) has a completion/continuation metaphor that is well-suited to this. If you merely want to *reunite* with some async work, then `Join()` will work, but there is no point starting a thread and *immediately* calling `Join` - you might as well just do the work on the current thread instead if that is your intent.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add the TPL syntax here for completeness (see my previous comment).

```
Task task = new Task(() => FetchQuotes(arg));
task.Start();
```

The task library has plenty of options for running on the calling thread, or async on one or many threads etc.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx